# RDS Drive and Clipboard Redirection Not Working

Tags: remote-desktop, file-transfer, paste, rds

I am experiencing an RDS Clipboard Redirection problem that is driving me crazy. I have an RDS environment with one gateway server 2012 r2. Users are not able to copy and paste to between client and host pc through RDP and they also do not get their local drives redirected. What I have tried so far:
- Used RSOP / Group Policy Modeling to determine that no policy is blocking drive or clipboard redirection
- Creating a policy to explicitly allow it didn't work
- Restarting RDClip process made no difference
- Settings are correct on RDP Client (allowing redirection of everything)
- Redirection is allowed on the Session Collection
- The registry on all servers is setup to allow redirection
- If I login Bypassing the gateway there is no issue.
- We don't use connection authorization policies we use resource authorization polices and I can't see any option to block or allow redirection in these polices as mentioned by Justin1250 in this Spiceworks post:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1477468-rds-limiting-printer-redirection-to-a-group
All Servers are Windows Server 2012 and client machines are Windows 10. Does anyone know or have an idea why?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this myself not too long ago and discovered that with 2012R2 things don't work the way they are advertised. I know this is contrary to the documentation but the solution here is to allow drive redirection. I honestly don't remember all the specifics, but setting the GPO to allow Clipboard redirection alone isn't enough. You will need them both enabled.